Is there a way in tableau to select the maximum value of a column, based on other columns?
I have three columns: a column of dates, a column of numerical values, and a a column of strings (states for example). I would like to create a column that assigns a 1 to any row in which the numerical value column is the largest value for each date and each string, and a 0 for all else. Is there a way to do this? For example, say there is are 5 different rows for every date in a year and every state. One out of each of these 5 rows should have a value of 1, as this row has the maximum numerical value out of the 5.
I tried using SQL in my access database to create a calculated column but found no luck. I also attempted to use the FIXED function in tableau but since my data sits on top of an access database, that function wasn't available to me.

The easiest solution does involve level of detail calculations, either fixed or otherwise. Luckily, you can easily create a (Hyper) extract of your access database, which supports LOD and some functions that Access doesn't. Then you just need to periodically refresh your extract to see recent changes to the original Access data.
The typical approach has two parts:

Create an LOD calculation that returns the maximum value for each group of data rows that you want. For example, define a calculated field called Max_Value_Per_Date as { FIXED [My_Date_Field] : MAX([My_Value_Field]) } This assumes your My_Date_Field has the data type date instead of date-time. If it does include times, you can use the Date_Trunc() to group at the level you want.
Create your field to flag the high value rows. For example, define a calculated field called Has_Max_Value_For_Date? as [My_Value] = [Max_Value_Per_Date]. Note this calculated field has a boolean data type instead of integer as requested, i.e. True and False instead of 1 and 0. The question mark in the field name is intended to aid clarity.

One other point, as you work with the data realize that is possible to have more than one State with the top value for a date -- i.e. a tie for first place. In that case, both states will return True. So take that into account when you interpret the results.

How would I be able to do this for 2 different columns; not just Date but also State?

In step one, add [State] to the LOD calculation i.e. { FIXED [My_Date_Field], [State] : MAX([My_Value_Field]) }

@RossColeman if this answers your question, best practice on StackOverflow is to accept and upvote the answer. That gets the responder reputation but also lets future readers know which answers addressed the question
